# How can I get/recognize the IP(s) from which FACEBOOK access shared URL?

Tags: facebook, ip, share

Actually, I was working with social sharing with Facebook. Facebook needs to access the shared url to get the open graph meta tags.
As I am working with test site that is under construction, we cant make it publicly accessible. But what we can do, we can permit access for ip(s). So to make sure Facebook can access our urls, we need to permit ip(s) which facebook used to get shared urls meta data.

Good idea and suggestion is much appreciable.

Thanks,
Sumoy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this -

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/ApplicationSecurity/#facebook_scraper

```
...accurate as of March 2013.

31.13.24.0/21
31.13.64.0/18
66.220.144.0/20
69.63.176.0/20
69.171.224.0/19
74.119.76.0/22
103.4.96.0/22
173.252.64.0/18
204.15.20.0/22

2401:db00::/32
2620:0:1c00::/40
2a03:2880::/32
```

Comment: Thanks. that would help. Just wondering if I could get similar list for twiiter and linkedin